# How to refactor this kind of situation

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, virtual-functions

I am implementing an algorithm with several computation modes in C++, and now I found the my class is too huge and difficult to maintain, so I want to apply some design pattern to refactor it. But I have little experience in software engineering. Thank you so much if I can get some idea or hints about which design pattern to use and how to deal with it[image]

My algorithm runs like the graph above. There are two issues.

1. For each function (`f1(),f2(),f3(),f3S()`) I have three different implementation. So now I have `f1a(),f1b(),f1c(),f2a(),f2b(),f2c(),f3a()....` totally 12 functions in the header file.
2. `f3S()` can substitute `f2()+f3()`, so I call the two way `quick mode` and `normal mode`

I was thinking `bridge pattern` , however, the `a,b,c` implementation and `quick,normal` mode can not totally vary independent. I still need implementation of every `f1a(),f1b()...`   not `f1(),f2()..` and `a(),b()..` then combine them.

also I am thinking the structure like this (some parts are omitted)
[image]

But if I want to do `dynamic binding`-- `class1 c = new QuickMode()`(I hope I used the right term) , I need to put abstract virtual function `f2(),f3(),f3S()` in Class1, but if the object is a `Quick Mode` one, but I call `f2()`it is certainly wrong, but it actually have a pointer of it.

I am sorry for the long post, I have little experience of OO programming and it had already bothered me for a few days. Really thankful if someone can give me some ideas.

Comment: Can you mix `f1a` with `f2b`, or you need to use only *b* implementation ?

Comment: Is the implementation of `QuickMode` is exactly `NormalMode.f2(); NormalMode.f3()` ? If so,, you can use composition for it and not inheritance.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you! I need to keep both implementations

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, Thank you! but it is not the `QuickMode` is different from `f2()+f3()` link together.

Comment: It seems you have just `Algorithm(f1, QuickMode(f3s))` or `Algorithm(f1, NormalMode(f2, f3))`.